# ScriptBlock Not Executing in PowerShell

Tags: .net, powershell

I am trying to execute an `.exe` file with `PowerShell` by doing:

```
$myExe = Join-Path $scriptDir "\bin\my\myProgram.exe" 
 $job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock{ 
        & $myExe }
```

But it doesn't execute. When in type in the file path in `$myExe`, the program works as expected, but when I use the above code, nothing happens. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong; or, why I'm not getting the expected results?

To be clear, the expected result (at this point) is to get a firewall warning. Again, when I type in the path directly to the PS console, the firewall warning comes up, but using the above code, nothing seems to happen. I've also tried to check the status using `Get-Process` but the result is the `$job` variable, saying it's `running`.

UPDATE:

Running:

```
$myExe = Join-Path $scriptDir "\bin\my\myProgram.exe"
& $prndExe
```

Causes PowerShell to hang

UPDATE 2:

When I do the following, the program works and the process starts:

```
 Start-Job -ScriptBlock{ & "C:\path\Music\source\p\android\test\Automation\bin\mym\myProgram.exe"}
```

But using the above code doesn't. This leads me to believe I'm doing something wrong with the `Start-Job` cmdlet?

Comment: Have you debugged [$myExe] to make sure the full path is correct? Also, Start-Job is for background processes. Is this supposed to be a background process?

Comment: so & $myExe works outside of the start-job scriptblock?

Comment: What is the value of $myExe when its used in Start-Job? Is it a valid path? Have you verified?

Comment: @TheOptimusPrimus I am writing the content of `$myExe` to the console, and then taking that output and putting it into the console to get it to 'work'. When I use `& $myExe` outside of the `scriptBlock` the program just hangs.

Comment: Yes, the path is valid: `C:\my\Music\source\lk\android\test\Automation\bin\myfolder\myProgram.exe`. I have taken that output and put it into the console, and had the expected result. Would running this as a background process make it run differently?

Comment: when you say "firewall warning comes up" - do you mean a gui?  do you have to press some key to get past the dialog?

Comment: Yes @Jimbo, that is exactly what happens when I put the path directly into the console.

Comment: I think start-job is wrong, you dont need this as a background process.

Comment: What difference does it make if it is in the background or not? It should work the same regardless; shouldn't it?

Comment: It wouldn't work the same either way. A background job won't give you output until you query the job object. Are you expecting a window to open or output at the console? You won't get that with a background job. Are you using **Get-Job** job to check whether it's running and **Receive-Job** to get the output?

Comment: @AdiInbar, I'm not expecting either of those things. My `exe` file is basically a program I want to run in the background. I don't interact with it (input or output), but it performs operations that I need to test.

Comment: Did you check it with **Get-Job**? If so, what's the output? If the job is listed, get the output with `Receive-Job <job's Id as shown in Get-Job>` and see if there are any error messages.

Comment: When I do the `get-job` the status says 'running' but the exe isn't showing up in the `get-process`

Comment: Can you post the output of **Get-Job**? Also, did you check for errors with **Receive-Job**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the solution to this issue (one that is NOT listed in the documentation, and should be) is that if you are using variables inside `ScriptBlock` you have to use the `ArgumentList` and pass in those variables.

So to get my scriptblock working, I did:

```
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock{  
    $myExe = $args[0]

    & $myExe
} -ArgumentList @($myExe)
```

Comment: I'm confused...the first line sets **$myExe** to a path to an exe file (`$myExe = Join-Path $scriptDir "\bin\my\myProgram.exe"`), and your entire script block is `& $myExe`...so where are the variables?

Comment: That is my point. When I set `$myExe` it is set outside the script block, so in order for me to use it, I have to pass it in as a parameter. Don't ask me why, but that is how it's working.

Comment: You have to pass it as a parameter because jobs run in a different process. The variables don't exist there.